# How do assign a variable an input as the value in a function and allow it to be accessed?

Tags: function, variables

I know that this is probably a simple fix, but I'm pretty new at programing.

```
def main2():
    x = int(input("What is the length of your rectangle?:  "))
    y = int(input("What is the width of your rectangle?:  "))
    z = int(input("What is the height of your rectangle?:  "))
    print(area2())

def area2():
    return(x * y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2()
```

My problem is that I am getting a "'variable' not accessed." Because of this, my program is not using the variables later in the code.

I've tried pretty stupid stuff that I expected to not work because I don't know very much code.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post the full code as plain text.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't know (1) how to **declare** a function such that it takes arguments, and (2) how to **call** a function with arguments?

Comment: I edited it so that it has my code as plain text. Also, no. I know how, but to me it made more sense to assign the variable inside "main2" instead of making "main2" have an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variable to the function. Inside main2() change the line with print() to this:

```py
print(area2(x, y))
```

You should also change your function to accept two variables.

```py
def area2(x, y):
    return(x * y)
```

Otherwise, make x,y as global:

```
global x,y
```

Then you don't need to pass the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are only available from inside the region they were created in. It's called scopes, you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

Whenever you reference a variable (for example `x`), it tries to resolve the variable by looking for it in local scope, and if it's not there, it tries to find it in parent scope.

So, in your code:

```py
def main2():
    # x is declared in this scope, body of `main2`
    x = int(input("What is the length of your rectangle?:  "))
    # y is declared in this scope, body of `main2`
    y = int(input("What is the width of your rectangle?:  "))
    z = int(input("What is the height of your rectangle?:  "))
    print(area2())

def area2():
    # there is no x and no y in this scope
    # nor in the global scope
    return(x * y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main2()
```

In your case, it would be best to pass `x` and `y` as arguments:

```py
def main2():
    x = int(input("What is the length of your rectangle?:  "))
    y = int(input("What is the width of your rectangle?:  "))
    z = int(input("What is the height of your rectangle?:  "))
    print(area2(x, y))

def area2(x, y):
    return(x * y)
```

You can read more about functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)